# The report definition is not valid rdlc file

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I have a report that creates a PDF file upon load its using rdlc file type, one of our developer of the company has left and now when I try to open the same report in my Visual studio 2017 it gives me the following error.

`The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded`

How can we fix this issue? We need to edit this file but each time we edit it causes this issue.

Comment: There are a number of exact Google hits for that error, have you taken a look? It's probably just a matter of version incompatibility with vs 2017.

Comment: Looks like the report needs to be run in 2016.  I would suggest downloading VS2016 and see if that changes things.  Personally, my company has reports built in VS2005, VS2008, VS2012, and VS2016 and these need to be used with the proper software as we use different versions of SSRS Report Manager for different clients.Could be as simple as getting 2016 and it'll work fine.

Comment: Thanks, guys, it was the matter of downloading the newer version, it was giving issues with the download too because it couldn't file the SQL server types but I chopped down the process and put in the dll files only for the newer version in the bin folder and had it working thanks again @Crowcoder and Steve